# Get Location without using GPS and without Google Services via official API

Tags: android

I wonder if it's possible to get a location without Google Services and without using GPS (and thus using `NETWORK_PROVIDER`) on an Android device. My current code looks like this:

```
public void onButtonTap(View view) {

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // we're done here
        printLocation(location);
    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
};

String provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = null;
try {
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
} catch (SecurityException se) { 
}
if(location != null) {
    // we're done here
    printLocation(location);
}
if(location == null) {
    try {
        locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(provider, locationListener, null);
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
    }
} // end of onButtonTab (formatting issues)

private void printLocation(Location location) {
    String latitude = String.format(Locale.US, "%.4f", location.getLatitude());
    String longitude = String.format(Locale.US, "%.4f", location.getLongitude());
    String slocation = "lat: " + latitude + ", lon: " + longitude;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), slocation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

So I basically query for the last location and if there's none I request an update. This works for `PASSIVE_PROVIDER` (if there's GPS activity) and of course for `GPS_PROVIDER` but I don't get a location with `NETWORK_PROVIDER`. The listeners method `onLocationChanged` never gets called. The app has the right permissions and `locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)` is true.

Is this functionality just not working because there's no database (owned by Google and provided by Google Services) to compare against? Or does AOSP build it's own database over time (learning from GPS Data)? I doubt the later.

Little extra question: I can't use [Fused Location Provider API](https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/) as I don't have Google Services installed, can I?

Comment: Do you have the WiFi radio enabled when you're testing this code?

Comment: Yes Wi-Fi is enabled (connected to a network, seeing >= 3 other networks).

Comment: There might not be Wi-Fi location data available, but `NETWORK_PROVIDER` also works based on the cell towers and might need a SIM card and access to the cellular network for that to work. Always creating a new `LocationListener` on the button press seems a bit weird, but probably that's not the problem if the object(s) remains in existence. And _"The fused location provider is a location API in Google Play services "_ Google says, so they are tied together.

Comment: SIM card was inserted. It seems like without Google Services I have to use GPS only.